# String parsing: For loop Windows Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I've spent a while reading through http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html, going through various other questions, and trying a lot of different little command-line variations of the examples, but still haven't gotten a simple for loop task down yet.

Basically, I want to do something where the command is something like

```
FOR /f %%G in ("1 2 7 16 21 26 688") do(
    echo %%G
)
```

The output I want to get is

```
1
2
...
688
```

But all I get is

```
1
```

And then it exits.  Through experimenting with various arguments (i.e. have tried "tokens=*", echo %%G echo %%H, "delims= "), nothing gets the desired output.  Rather, I get stuff like

```
1 2 7 ... 688
```

or

```
1 %H
```

Comment: `/f` is (basically) for processing files (or command outputs). To process elements (a list), use `for` without `/f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this way with a batch file :

```
@echo off
FOR %%G in (1 2 7 16 21 26 688) do (
    echo %%G
)
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's important to express that you want the 7 specific items extracted by calling for tokens=1-7.
Token 1 will be %%G, with each successive, stipulated token using %%H, %%I, etc.
Wanting to express one line for each token comes by echoing them 1 echo command at a time for each token's variable, either as one per line stacked or parenthetically grouped sequentially with &s:
do (echo %%G) & (echo %%H) & (echo %%I)... etc

In total, the following worked for me:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7" %%G in ("1 2 7 16 21 26 688") do (  
    echo %%G  
    echo %%H  
    echo %%I  
    echo %%J  
    echo %%K  
    echo %%L  
    echo %%M  
    )
```